# Haskell Ambiguous Occurrence (+) when defining a vector

Tags: haskell

I would like to define a 3D vector, with `x, y, z` coordinates. Vectors can be added using the `(+)` operator and the length can be calculated using the `length` function

I get the following error, if I would like to compile it:

```
It could refer to either `Prelude.+',
                             imported from `Prelude' at hello.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in `GHC.Num')
                          or `Main.+', defined at hello.hs:9:14
```

The code is:

```
data Vec3 = Vec3 {
    x :: Float,
    y :: Float,
    z :: Float
} deriving (Eq,Show)

(+) :: Vec3 -> Vec3 -> Vec3
(Vec3 a b c) + (Vec3 t u w) = Vec3 (a+t) (b+u) (c+w)

length :: Vec3 -> Float
length (Vec3 a b c) = sqrt( a*a + b*b + c*c )

vv = Vec3 1.5 0.7 2.2

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ length vv
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To literally overload the `+` operator, you would need to define a `Num` instance, like

```
instance Num Vec3 where
  Vec3 a b c + Vec3 t u w = Vec3 (a+t) (b+u) (c+w)
  Vec3 a b c * Vec3 t u w = ...
```

This is in fact what the [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-V3.html) and [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.18.0.0/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Data.html#g:2) libraries do for their vector types, as does (basically) also the highly popular [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) Python framework.

I would strongly recommend *against* this, because the semantics of vector spaces are in quite some sense incompatible with those of plain scalar numbers. In particular, you need to define multiplication here; the only way that properly works with these type signatures is component-wise, like with Matlab's `.*` operator

```
  Vec3 a b c * Vec3 t u w = Vec3 (a*t) (b*u) (c*w)
```

but that doesn't make mathematically sense for vectors as such, only for the expansion of vectors *in a particular basis*. Also it leads easily to bugs if you can erroneously define a vector as a single number (which in `linear` pastes the number into all vector components, urgh!)

A better fit is the `Monoid` class, as [suggested by Reaktormonk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42873409/745903). However you'll probably find yourself also wanting a scaling operation

```
(*^) :: Float -> Vec3 -> Vec3
μ *^ Vec3 t u w = Vec3 (μ*t) (μ*u) (μ*w)
```

(unlike component-wise multiplication, [this *is* defined for any vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)), and `Monoid` doesn't offer this.

The correct class for this sort of type is [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.4/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html).

```
instance AdditiveGroup Vec3 where
  Vec3 a b c ^+^ Vec3 t u w = Vec3 (a+t) (b+u) (c+w)
  negateV v = (-1)*^v
instance VectorSpace Vec3 where
  type Scalar Vec3 = Float
  μ *^ Vec3 t u w = Vec3 (μ*t) (μ*u) (μ*w)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: you're trying to overload the + operator, which is already defined in the Prelude.

Haskell doesn't *technically* allow operator overloading the way most other languages do, so you can't just define a new function called `+` because this function is already used for adding scalar numbers together.

Instead you could try calling it something else, like `addV`, or maybe `>+<` or something

Answer (score 3):

I tried going around by

```
import Prelude hiding ((+), length)
```

but then you don't have access to addition anymore. I'd recommend going the `Monoid` route here. I'd rename `length` to `vlength` or similar, because IIRC there's no direct concept of that in any typeclass.

```
import Data.Monoid

data Vec3 = Vec3 {
    x :: Float,
    y :: Float,
    z :: Float
} deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Monoid Vec3 where
  mappend (Vec3 a b c) (Vec3 t u w) = Vec3 (a+t) (b+u) (c+w)
  mempty = Vec3 0 0 0

vlength :: Vec3 -> Float
vlength (Vec3 a b c) = sqrt( a*a + b*b + c*c )

vv = Vec3 1.5 0.7 2.2
v2 = Vec3 1.0 2.7 3.4

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ vv <> v2
  print $ vlength vv
```

Comment: +1 for _not_ recommending a `Num` instance, but `Monoid` is also not that great IMO as it doesn't allow scalar multiplication.